# Excess elements in scalar initializer code compiles with gcc but not g++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

Just curious why this code (that it is obviously wrong) using gcc it compiles, however the same code using the g++ it does not.

```
int main()
{
    char *foo = {"bar", "fred", "bob"};

    return 0;
}
```

gcc gives this warning but still compiles and generates the binary:

> % **gcc -o x x.c**
>
> x.c: In function ‘main’: x.c:3:5: warning: excess
> elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default] x.c:3:5: warning:
> (near initialization for ‘foo’) [enabled by default] x.c:3:5: warning:
> excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default] x.c:3:5:
> warning: (near initialization for ‘foo’) [enabled by default]
>
> % **ls -l x**
>
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 overdrive overdrive 6593 Jul 28 21:51 x

g++ gives this error and no any binary as an output:

> % **g++ -o y y.cpp**
>
> y.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> y.cpp:3:38: error: scalar object ‘foo’ requires one element in initializer
>
> % **ls -l y**
>
> ls: cannot access y: No such file or directory

gcc and g++ version I am using is:

> % **g++ --version**
> g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
> Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
> warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Is there any good reason why this compiles in gcc and not in g++? or it is clearly a bug?

Comment: Compilers are certainly allowed to compile invalid code - whether or not it works as intended is undefined

Comment: Remember: C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: Which is best `g++` that gives you an error, or `gcc` that gives you undefined behaviour?

Comment: You can make gcc be stricter about it, too ([demo](http://ideone.com/NM8dmF)).

Comment: Well, my question it was more if this was a bug of gcc compiler, because clearly char* should never initializes an array of pointers to char.

Comment: Since a warning is issued, there's no difference from issuing an error. A compiler implementer may decide that issuing a warning and moving on, is better than issuing an error. This however doesn't mean that the code is legitimate C or C++.

Comment: Issuing a warning on a construct that has a clear compilation and issuing a warning on a construct that is confusing and potentially undefined are two different things. Compilers are allowed to support constructs outside the standard, but if a construct is compiled, we should at least be able to understand the decision that was made by the compiler. Typically a warning indicates the compiler made a decision. Lack of a warning or error for an undefined construct would probably indicate a bug and a gap in the semantic checking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a good reason for making it a hard error in C++, even on implementations that historically accepted in C:

```
template <typename T, int = sizeof(T{1,2,3,4})>
void f();

template <typename T>
void f(...) { }

int main() { f<int>(); }
```

This is a valid C++ program. A compiler *must not* reject this with a complaint about an ambiguous call or a linker error complaining that the first overload is undefined: the C++ standard requires `f<int>()` to call the second overload, because the first overload has a substitution error.

With this in mind, implementations are faced with two options: they can either consistently reject excess initialisers, or they can carefully determine in which contexts the standard requires them to be rejected, and in which contexts the implementation can continue to allow them. The GCC and clang developers have opted to consistently reject them, which is significantly easier to implement.

C does not have any such facilities that determine expression validity at compile-time, so for C there is no way for such an extension to cause valid programs to be rejected.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. There is one part that I do not truly understand: what it is really doing this part? int = sizeof(T{1,2,3,4})

Comment: @BorjaTarraso It takes the size of the expression `T{1,2,3,4}` (which constructs a `T` object from the initialiser `{1,2,3,4}`), and then proceeds to ignore that size. So it doesn't really matter what `T{1,2,3,4}` is, it just has to be valid. It is valid if `T` is `int[4]`, because `{1,2,3,4}` is a valid array initialiser and of the right length, but it is not valid if `T` is `int` or `int[1]`. Because the expression makes that overload of `f` invalid, the other overload of `f` (the one that is valid for all types) becomes the only function that `f<int>` can possibly refer to.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C 2011 Standard

> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally
>   enclosed in braces

The verb shall means that the compiler shall issue a diagnostic message,:)

So it is a feature or a bug of the compiler.:)

According to the C Standard

> 1 A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic
>   message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a
>   preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a
>   violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is
>   also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined

Comment: No, "shall" does not mean "shall issue an error", it does not mean that at all. All that is required is a diagnostic. It does not have to be labelled "error", and once the diagnostic is issued, the standard places no further requirements on the implementation. The *only* time an implementation *must not* successfully translate a program is if it contains an `#error` directive.

Comment: Downvote removed, though I don't really think that answers the question: it just shows that both behaviours are valid, but it doesn't answer the question of whether it could be intentional or an accident.